# Contours from a image appear very sloppy with cv2 findContours. How to improve?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to find the contour of an image using cv2. There are many related questions, but the answer always appear to be very specific and not applicable to my case.

I have an black and white image that I change into color.

```
thresh = cv2.cvtColor(thresh, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY) 
plt.imshow(thresh)
```

[image]

Next, I try to find the contours.

```
image, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

and then I visualize it by plotting it on a black background.

```
blank_image = np.zeros((thresh.shape[0],thresh.shape[1],3), np.uint8) 
img = cv2.drawContours(blank_image, contours, 0, (255,255,255), 3)
plt.imshow(img)
```

[image: Contour image]

The contour follows the actual contour, i.e. surrounding the whole thing. How do I get something like this very bad paint impression:

[image]

Comment: I think the artifact you're looking for is "edges", not "contours".

Comment: Provide a [mcve] that reproduces the issue, along with a pristine input image. State version of OpenCV used. | Why do the coordinates in the second plot go well past 4000? Does that mean your input image is that large?

Comment: I'm using version 3.4.1. Yes, the input image is that large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Canny edge detection to do this:

[image]

```
import cv2
frame = cv2.imread("iCyrOT3.png")                       # read a frame
gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)          # turn it gray
edges = cv2.Canny(gray, 100, 200)                       # get canny edges
cv2.imshow('Test', edges)                               # display the result
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: This works. Strangely enough, it doesn't work on the original image which is around 4000x4000. Apparently the size needs to be small enough to work.

Comment: @MitchellvanZuylen, that's very interesting. I'll experiment with it. I have a solution using contours too but I have to clean it up before posting.